# Another question about theorem 2.10 in Hatcher's algebraic topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Following up the beautiful response of Adam Lowrance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577827/question-about-theorem-in-hatchers-algebraic-topology),

I wish to ask an additional question about a proof that Hatcher gives of theorem 2.10 in his book on algebraic topology (that homotopic maps induce the same homomorphisms in homology).

Here's the proof:

[image]

My question is this: I do not understand why the region between graph$(\varphi_i)$ and graph($\varphi_{i-1})$ is the simplex $[v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_i, \ldots, w_n]$.

From this it would follow that $\Delta^n \times I$ is the union of the $(n+1)$-simplices $[v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_i, \ldots, w_n]$. However, how do I see that each intersects the next in an $n$-simplex face?

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph of $\varphi_i$ is the set of all affine combinations of $v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_{i+1}, \ldots, w_n$, and the graph of $\varphi_{i-1}$ is the set of all affine combinations of $v_0, \ldots, v_{i-1}, w_i, \ldots, w_n$. From this it follows that the region between the graphs of $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_{i-1}$ is the set of all affine combinations of
$$
\{v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_{i+1}, \ldots, w_n\} \cup \{v_0, \ldots, v_{i-1}, w_i, \ldots, w_n\} = \{v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_i, \ldots, w_n\}.
$$
To see this, observe that any point $(t_0, \ldots, t_n, t)$ between the graphs $\big(($i.e. with $\varphi_i(t_0, \ldots, t_n) \leq t \leq \varphi_{i-1}(t_0, \ldots, t_n)\big)$ is an affine combination of $(t_0, \ldots, t_n, \varphi_i(t_0, \ldots, t_n))$ and $(t_0, \ldots, t_n, \varphi_{i-1}(t_0, \ldots, t_n))$, which in turn are affine combinations of $\{v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_{i+1}, \ldots, w_n\}$ and $\{v_0, \ldots, v_{i-1}, w_i, \ldots, w_n\}$, respectively. Conversely, you can check that any affine combination of $\{v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_i, \ldots, w_n\}$ lies between the graphs of $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_{i-1}$.

Having established that the region between the graphs is $[v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_i, \ldots, w_n]$, we just need to show that this is an $(n+1)$-simplex. Well, $[v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_{i+1}, \ldots, w_n]$ is an $n$-simplex, so it's enough to check (as Hatcher observes) that the additional point $w_i$ does *not* lie in the $n$-simplex $[v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_{i+1}, \ldots, w_n]$ (the graph of $\varphi_i$). This is true since $w_i$ is the point $(0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0, 1)$, where the first 1 in the $i$th position, and $\varphi_i(0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ is $v_i$, not $w_i$ (again, where the 1 is in the $i$th position).

Finally, to see that the intersection of the two "consecutive" $(n+1)$-simplices is an $n$-simplex, note that one of the $(n+1)$-simplices is the region between the graphs of $\varphi_{i-1}$ and $\varphi_i$ (for some $i$), and the other is the region between the graphs of $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_{i+1}$. The intersection of these two regions is the graph of $\varphi_i$, which we've already determined is the $n$-simplex $[v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_{i+1}, \ldots, w_n]$.